# Reverse Y-Axis on Axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a GUI window on which I have an axes box and I'd like to reverse Y axis direction on this axes1 box when using a plot function. When I try to use lets say:

```
set(axes1,'YDir','reverse');
```

I get the following error

> Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line/set
>   There is no YDir property on the Line class.

when I check the properties of this axes1 I get

```
AlignVertexCenters: 'off'
            Annotation: [1x1 matlab.graphics.eventdata.Annotation]
          BeingDeleted: 'off'
            BusyAction: 'queue'
         ButtonDownFcn: ''
              Children: [0x0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
              Clipping: 'on'
                 Color: [1 0 0]
             CreateFcn: ''
             DeleteFcn: ''
           DisplayName: ''
      HandleVisibility: 'on'
               HitTest: 'on'
         Interruptible: 'on'
              LineJoin: 'round'
             LineStyle: '-'
             LineWidth: 1
                Marker: 'none'
       MarkerEdgeColor: 'auto'
       MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
            MarkerSize: 6
                Parent: [1x1 Axes]
         PickableParts: 'visible'
              Selected: 'off'
    SelectionHighlight: 'on'
                   Tag: ''
                  Type: 'line'
         UIContextMenu: [0x0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
              UserData: []
               Visible: 'on'
                 XData: [1x3937 double]
             XDataMode: 'manual'
           XDataSource: ''
                 YData: [1x3937 double]
           YDataSource: ''
                 ZData: [1x0 double]
           ZDataSource: ''
```

So I tried changing the YDir on the property inspector from normal to reverse and it didn't work.
I've tried using `flipud` and it just flips the line but not the values on the Y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what you're calling `axes1` is actually a [*line*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html) object. You can easily check this by getting the `Type` property of the object.

```
get(axes1, 'Type')

% Or in newer versions of MATLAB
class(axes1)
```

You'll want to instead set the `YDir` on it's *parent axes*. We can easily get that using the [`ancestor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ancestor.html?refresh=true) function.

```
hax = ancestor(axes1, 'axes');
set(hax, 'YDir', 'reverse')
```

Or more simply for your specific case:

```
set(axes1.Parent, 'YDir', 'reverse')
```

In the future, carefully read the *entire* contents of the error message. Here it is very explicit that your command isn't working because it's a line.

Comment: @LuisMendo Only if it's not within an `hggroup` and you're using 2014b+ :)

Comment: Well, the OP's example says the object has a `Parent` which is an axes object

Comment: @LuisMendo I agree. I'm just giving you a hard time!

Comment: Ok, ok. Note taken :-P

Comment: Hi @LuisMendo thanks, i'm new at 2015 I was using 2012 and I had no idea about Parents and Childs. I read it and didn't understand why axes1 was a Line instead of the axes object i have on the window. Thanks for the help, I had this code in 2012 (as said previously) and never had issues. Now I need to  read about this ancestors and parents thing, more controls but also more things to set...